# String meaning recognition / pattern recognition

Tags: java, string, machine-learning, pattern-recognition, text-classification

Does anybody know if there is some library which can solve this problem:

I have set of strings, for example screen resolutions with some text around it:

```
1024x768
1920x1080 (FullHD)
2560×1600 (Retina)
...
```

then I get another string like 800x600 or just "Retina" and I want to retrieve some
number which will represent probability that this string represents screen resolution (The value don't have to be in the set).

To be more specific consider that I have more classifications than just screen resolutions. Take for example frequencies of CPU, MB/GB of RAM etc. So the solution should be more generic and with some learning ability of course.

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Comment: Good point.. I forgot that... I want use it with java

Answer (score 0):

you could use the same technique demonstrated in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zacstewart/5978000).

Although he uses python and sci-kit learning, the code is very readable and you could use [weka](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/), [mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) or any similar library in JAVA.

Comment: I looked at it but I there is one problem. That python code takes existing words, that I can achieve, its not very hard. My problem is that I can get string which I don't have in database (this makes it more difficult). Imagine you will see string 800x600 and my question is: Is it resolution/frequency/MB of RAM? And you will tell me the probability for each. I slightly looked at Weka also but I'm afraid I will have this same problem.. I will read the documentation.. thanks anyway

Comment: you should research classification algorithms and choose which one fits your problem the best, the algorithms used to find out the number based on a given image sound similar to what you are trying to achieve, Good Luck.